# Convert keyword in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I want to convert a `DATETIME` field (DateOfBirth)... When I execute the following query it says invalid syntax near convert

```
SELECT e.Emp_Id,e.Emp_Name,e.Address,e.Department,
(convert(varchar, e.Date_Of_Birth, 103) as Date_Of_Birth) from Employee as e
```

But when I execute the below query it gives result but my dateofbirth column name is (No Column Name)

```
SELECT e.Emp_Id,e.Emp_Name,e.Address,e.Department,
(convert(varchar, e.Date_Of_Birth, 103)) from Employee as e
```

Why cant I give an alias name as column name to a convert function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the extra comma:

```
SELECT e.Emp_Id,e.Emp_Name,e.Address,e.Department, 
convert(varchar, e.Date_Of_Birth, 103) as Date_Of_Birth
FROM Employee as e
```

Comment: @Mitch sorry that was my editing mistake.. see my edited question

Comment: Does the query I posted work (note removed extra parentheses)?